# Data attribute returning undefined in loop

Tags: jquery

I cannot figure out why this returns undefined. Accessing the data-menu attribute elsewhere works just fine. Wondering if lack of sleep is is making me miss the obvious...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tileEmptyCheck = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tile-menu-container"));
  for (var i = 0; i < tileEmptyCheck.length; i++) {
    let temp = $(tileEmptyCheck[i]).data("emptyTile");
    console.log(temp);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s1t01" class="tile-menu-container" data-menu="yesMenu" data-emptyTile="notEmpty">
  Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of **`data-*`**,

The `data-*` attribute consists of two parts:

1. The attribute name **should not contain any uppercase letters**, and must be at least one character long after the prefix `"data-"`
2. The attribute value can be any string

So do not use like this `data-emptyTile=`. There if you change the name to lowercase like this `data-emptytile=` **or** `data-empty-tile=` it will work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Oh good grief, I camel cased it out of habit and didn't even see it. Working now. Thank you!